# Not able to open projects in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am watching  a few mango jumpstart videos provided on this link  http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Mango-Jump-Start . When I am watching video 3, there's an option called "code for the sample" which I downloaded but when I try and open the visual studio 2010 express edition for windowsphone project it gives an error message:

```
Unable to read the project file 'Wazup.csproj'.

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\anantha\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_03 
Advanced Silverlight (1).zip\03 Advanced Silverlight\Demo 1 
ApplicationBar-Navigation-Pivot\PivotDemo-End\Wazup\Wazup\Wazup.csproj'.
```

Please help

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you unzip / extract the files first before opening the project file.